# Cartesian Plane

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to define a function in Haskell that takes an integer argument c and returns the list of all points on the cartesian plane of the form `(x/c,y/c)` where `x` and `y` are integers.
`x/c` is between -2 and 1 and `y/r` is between -1 and 1

This is what I've gotten so far which I'm almost sure is right but I'm getting a parse error on input `=` when I run it particularly at this line: `cart xs ys c = [(y/c,x/c) | x <- xs, y <- ys]`

```
plane :: Int -> [a]
plane c = cart [-1*c .. 1*c] [-2*c .. 1*c] c
     cart xs ys c = [(y/c,x/c) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

A sample output would be: `plane 1` would generate:

```
[(-2.0, -1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), ( 0.0, -1.0), ( 1.0, -1.0),
 (-2.0,  0.0), (-1.0,  0.0), ( 0.0,  0.0), ( 1.0,  0.0),
 (-2.0,  1.0), (-1.0,  1.0), ( 0.0,  1.0), ( 1.0,  1.0)]
```

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing the `where`, other than that it looks like you have some type errors.

1. `[a]` is too general
2. `/` only works on fractional types.

so

```
plane :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
plane c = cart [-1*c .. 1*c] [-2*c .. 1*c] c where
    cart xs ys c = [(y `div` c,x `div` c) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

might be what you want.  Smallest change from what you have that more or less works.

Comment: thanks @PhilipJF. i keep making the smallest errors. One day I will conquer functional programming

Comment: `div` is `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, and thus returns only integral values, but I think real numbers or rationals are desired.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it.  `fromintegral` is a type 'glue' function that converts any value in the `Integral` type class to any other type in the `Num` typeclass.  The result type has to be in `RealFrac` (like `Double` or `Rational`) to use the `/` operator.

```
plane :: (Integral a, RealFrac b) => a -> [(b,b)] 
plane d = [(fI y / fI d,fI x / fI d) | x <- [-2*d..d], y <- [-d..d]] 
    where fI = fromIntegral
```